# Will a connection-string with ip be recognized as local ip and thus a request to database will be made without a network roundtrip?

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-2014

My application is on a server with IP **X**. The Connection-String in this application is defined as:

connectionString="Data Source=**X**\Instance;.."

Will the Application connect to the database over the network? Or will the ip be recognized as the local IP and thus the request to the database will be done directly without a network request?

Comment: No. It will ping the DNS to see where that IP lives. The bigger question is why is your application on the same server as your sql server? It is generally recommended to separate those to provide additional security and reduce resource contention.

Comment: The database queries should be processed as quickly as possible, thus the application should not lose any time for additional network traffic

Comment: Of course you run the risk that the cpu needed for the query will be consumed by the application. If you write your queries efficiently there shouldn't be a huge bottleneck with network traffic. Unless you need millions of rows by lots of people simultaneously this just seems like a weak argument to me. But it is your system. Is the extra picosecond to ping DNS going to cause an issue in your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server supports multiple transports - shared memory, named pipes and TCP/IP. If shared memory is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager, and you use any of these styles of connection strings, then the connection will first be attempted using shared memory:

```
(local)/instance
localhost/instance
./instance
servername/instance
```

If however, you use an IP address, then the connection will be attempted using TCP/IP.

You should read these MSDN articles:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187662(v=sql.130).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191260(v=sql.130).aspx